# DocumentTermMatrix in tm package does not return all words

Tags: r, text-mining, tm

I'm creating a document-term matrix with the tm-package in R, but some of the words in my corpus get lost in the process somewhere.

I will explain with an example. Let's say I have this small corpus

```
library(tm)
crps <- " more hours to my next class bout to go home and go night night"
crps <- VCorpus(VectorSource(crps))
```

When I use `DocumentTermMatrix()` from the tm-package, it will return these results:

```
dm <- DocumentTermMatrix(crps)
dm_matrix <- as.matrix(dm)
dm_matrix
# Terms
# Docs and bout class home hours more next night
# 1   1    1     1    1     1    1    1     2
```

However, what I want (and expected) is:

```
# Docs and bout class home hours more next night my  go to
#  1   1    1     1    1     1    1    1     2   1   2  1
```

Why does `DocumentTermMatrix()` skip the words "my","go"and "to"? Is there a way to control and fix this function?

Comment: I assume you are using the `tm`-package? What kind of object is `crps`? How did you get `crps`? Did you use something like `crps <- Corpus(VectorSource(some_text_string))`?

Comment: Yes i used `crps <-VCorpus(VectorSource(My_text))`

Answer (score 5):

`DocumentTermMatrix()` automatically discards words that are less than three characters. Therefore, the words `to`, `my` and `go` are not considered when constructing the document-term matrix.

From the help page `?DocumentTermMatrix`, you can see there's an optional argument called `control`. This optional argument has a number of default values for numerous things (see the help page `?termFreq` for more details). One of these defaults is a word length of at least three characters, i.e. `wordLengths = c(3, Inf)`. You can change this to accommodate for all words, regardless of word length:

```
dm <- DocumentTermMatrix(my_corpus, control = list(wordLengths=c(1, Inf))

inspect(dm)
# <<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 1, terms: 11)>>
# Non-/sparse entries: 11/0
# Sparsity           : 0%
# Maximal term length: 5
# Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
#
#    Terms
# Docs and bout class go home hours more my next night to
#    1   1    1     1  2    1     1    1  1    1     2  2
```

Comment: For the record, this also happened to me with `TermDocumentMatrix(texts)`. I have a long NLP pipeline and I have been perplexed as to why some preprocessing steps are discarding words instead of increasing their frequency. I have solved this via `TermDocumentMatrix(texts, control = list(wordLengths=c(1, Inf)))` as indicated in the answer.