# DocumentTermMatrix misses some words

Tags: r, nlp, tm

I am using DocumentTermMatrix to find a list of keywords in a long text. Most of the words in my list are correctly found, but there are a couple that are missing. Now, I would love to post here a minimal working example, but the problem is: there is one of the words ("insolvency", so not a short word as in the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46639795/documenttermmatrix-in-tm-package-does-not-return-all-words)) in a document of 32 pages which is missed. Now, this word is actually in page 7 of the text. But if I reduce my text with `text <- text[7]`, then DocumentTermMatrix actually finds it! So I am not able to reproduce this with a minimal working example...

Do you have any ideas?

Below a sketch of my script:

```
library(fastpipe)
library(openxlsx)
library(tm)

`%>>%` <- fastpipe::`%>>%`

source("cleanText.R") # Custom function to clean up the text from reports

keywords_xlsx <- read.xlsx(paste0(getwd(),"/Keywords.xlsx"),
                           sheet = "all",
                           startRow = 1,
                           colNames = FALSE,
                           skipEmptyRows = TRUE,
                           skipEmptyCols = TRUE)

keywords <- keywords_xlsx[1] %>>%
  tolower(as.character(.[,1]))

# Custom function to read pdfs
read <- readPDF(control = list(text = "-layout"))

# Extract text from pdf
report <- "my_report.pdf"
document <- Corpus(URISource(paste0("./Annual reports/", report)), readerControl = list(reader = read))
text <- content(document[[1]]) 

text <- cleanText(report, text) # This is a custom function to clean up the texts

# text <- text[7] # If I do this, my word is found! Otherwise it is missed

# Create a corpus  
text_corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(text))


matrix <- t(as.matrix(inspect(DocumentTermMatrix(text_corpus,
                                                 list(dictionary = keywords,
                                                      list(wordLengths=c(1, Inf))
                                                 )
))))
  
  
words <- sort(rowSums(matrix),decreasing=TRUE) 
df <- data.frame(word = names(words),freq=words)
```

Comment: What package are all the non-base functions (e.g. `Corpus`, `cleanText`) from?

Comment: `Corpus` is from the `tm` package (I believe?). `cleanText` is my own function, defined on another script. Going to edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your use of `inspect`. Only use inspect to check if your code is working and to see if a dtm has any values. **Never** use `inspect` inside functions / transformations, because `inspect` by default only shows the firs 10 rows and 10 columns of a document term matrix.

Also if you want to transpose the outcome of a dtm, use `TermDocumentMatrix`.

Your last line should be:

```
mat <- as.matrix(TermDocumentMatrix(text_corpus,
                                    list(dictionary = keywords,
                                         list(wordLengths=c(1, Inf)))))
```

Note that turning a dtm / tdm into a matrix will use a lot more memory than having the data inside a sparse matrix.