Word Cloud in R, R removing my specific words
I am working on my word cloud using R.
In my data, I have many "AI" but the word cloud does not recognize this word. ChatGPT respond that I have 43 AI in my data. Here is my code:
install.packages("wordcloud")
install.packages("tm")
install.packages("RColorBrewer")
library("wordcloud")
library("tm")
library(ggplot2)
library(readxl) 
library(RColorBrewer)

#####Good Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oVVvG035vQc

##################################
# Read the data from the Excel file
data <- read_excel("/Users/home/Dropbox/ATD/ATD24 In-Person & Virtual for Delegations.xlsx", sheet = "1. Schedule")

# Extract the session title column
# Replace 'session' with the exact name of your column
titles <- data$`Session Title (Session)`
# Create a text corpus
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(titles))

# Define custom stopwords
my_stopwords <- c("learning", "development", "inperson", "streamed", "live", "design", "training", "new", "better", "can", "beyond", "like", "know", "without", "almost", "don't")


# Define a color palette
colors <- brewer.pal(8, "Dark2")  # Choose a palette from RColorBrewer
# To get more colors you can repeat the palette
colors <- colorRampPalette(colors)(100)  # Adjust the number to control color variations

# Preprocess the text data
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, c(stopwords("english"), my_stopwords))
corpus[[83]][1]
##create table
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus)
m<- as.matrix(tdm)
v<-sort(rowSums(m),decreasing = TRUE)
d<-data.frame(word=names(v),freq=v)
# View(d)
# Generate the word cloud
wordcloud(corpus, min.freq=1,max.words = 500, random.order = FALSE, rot.per = 0.35, scale = c(2, 0.1), use.r.layout=FALSE,colors=brewer.pal(8, "Set2"))



For example, I have "Harness AI to Transform Your Learning Ecosystem" in 83th row, I got d that I have ecosystem, harness, learning, transform, and your. SO I lost AI only (I think to is removed due to my stopwords).
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus[[83]])
m<- as.matrix(tdm)
v<-sort(rowSums(m),decreasing = TRUE)
d<-data.frame(word=names(v),freq=v)

Thank you for your help in advance.
R in word cloud remove the specific words

Thank you Dave for your response. I am novice to the programming, and could not found the option for including 2 letters as well. Can you help me how to include the two letter characters? I think it might be in the termdocumentmatrix option, but I could not found.

Take a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46645564/1714.  It's not your stop words: DocumentTermMatrix() discards words that are less than three characters.  You'll need to provide wordLengths in the control parameter

Thank you Hobo and Dave! I am learning StackOverFlow, and in my previous answer, the reply asked me to accept the answer. I want to appreciate both of your help, but I cannot find the accept button. How can I do that?

Hi Simon - happy to help.  Thanks for wanting to do the right thing, but because we only commented (neither of us provided an answer as such) there's nothing to accept.  I'd suggest upvoting the answer I pointed you (assuming it helped).
